# Clarification about percentage calculus

Tags: fractions, percentages

Why if we want to know what percentage of 16 is 4 we do

```
4/16
```

and not

```
16/4
```

?

4/16 gives you the answer, because it's equal to 0.25, that is equal to 25%, while 16/4 doesn't (I guess); but I don't understand the logic. It seems more natural to me to do 16/4, because if I want to know the percentage I would split the 16 by 4 to know how many parts does the 4 create (in my logic the number of parts created define the percentage).
So if I try to do 16/4 I get 4, but then I don't know how to go on to get 25%.
Maybe there's a way to obtain the result in the way I'm proposing but I don't know it.

I hope my question doesn't sound stupid, but this is one of the many basic things that I'm lacking in math to fully understand its logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentages are always expressed as a part of 1.

As you say $r = {p\over q}$ gives you the number of parts of $q$ in $p$, but then you have to compute the number of parts of $r$ in $1$ to get a percentage. So your percentage is indeed ${1\over r}$.

And

$${1\over r} = {1\over {p\over q}} = {q\over p}$$

Comment: Percentages are expressed as a part of 1 because it can be expressed as 1.00, that means 100/100, that is 100%, right?

So my next step, after having obtained 4 from 16/4, is to do 1/4 and obtain 0.25. Mmh so i wasn't wrong while thinking that way

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Per cent (Latin) = Per hundred (English).  Percent=Hundredth. I recall a story about the Harvard graduate who said he couldn't do percentages "because when I multiply 80% by 10% I get 800 %."  :)